# Query in multiple tables with MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

Table_1 has product 3 rows : ID, Quantity and Price.
Table_2 has 2 rows : ID, Special_note.

Not all products have a special note. When a product doesn't have a special note, there is no row for that product in table 2.

I'm trying to use a select query that will get all the information from table_1 but also grab the special note from table_2 when there's one.

The problem I'm having right now is that if there is no special note, it won't grab the information in table_1 at all.

I understand why it's doing it but I don't know how to fix the query so that it returns all the products whether there is a special note or not.

```
 SELECT TABLE_1.ID, QUANTITY, PRICE, SPECIAL_NOTE
 FROM TABLE_1, TABLE_2
 WHERE TABLE_1.ID = TABLE_2.ID
```

I simplified the query a little bit for the purpose of this example.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.QUANTITY, t1.PRICE, t2.SPECIAL_NOTE
FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

**Update:**

To add a `WHERE` clause, e.g., where quantity >= 1, do this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.QUANTITY, t1.PRICE, t2.SPECIAL_NOTE
FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.QUANTITY >= 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Trying to grasp this new concept. Let's say I wanted to only grab the rows where quantity is at least 1. Where would I add the where query? After the LEFT OUTER JOIN line?

Comment: I have figured it out in a simple example! Trying to make it work with my actual very long and complicated query. Thanks a lot!